# typing "pod install" in the terminal shows an issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I type pod install in the terminal I see

```
-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.
```

I'm trying to follow the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg2_b_jrorU&authuser=0

and at the very end when I type pod install I see those words , this is what happened right before I got that issue :

```
:connected:~ ialvector$ cd Desktop/MySiri/
connected:MySiri ialvector$ pod init
[!] Existing Podfile found in directory
connected:MySiri ialvector$ open Podfile
connected:MySiri ialvector$ pod install
```

and I kept typing the same words and I was deleting the pod file that already existed so that the

```
[!] Existing Podfile found in directory
```

message wouldn't come up and I uninstalled cocoapods and reinstalled it and there is still an issue when I type pod install

The image I see is [image]

I put in a image of my pod file and the instructions on the revenue cat website
my pod file
[image]
instructions from revenue cat:
[image]

Comment: what does your Podfile look like?

Comment: Have you try remove your PodFile and init it again?

Comment: I added my pod file image and I add some more images for what I'm seeing

Comment: No pictures of code please.